# How to specify the parameter an objective function is minimized with respect to, using scipy.optimize.minimize()?

Tags: python, optimization, arguments, scipy-optimize-minimize

Suppose I have an objective function **f(a,b,c)**. I want to find the value of **b** that minimizes it, holding **a** and **c** constant, and to experiment with different combinations of **a** and **c**, I prefer not to write **f(a,b,c)** as **g(b)**.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(a,b,c):
    return((a+1)**2 + b + c/2)

res = minimize(f, x0=1, args=(a,c,),)
print(res.x)
```

Then how do I specify that **b** is the parameter that **f(a,b,c)** should be minimized with respect to? Does that parameter have to be expressed as **x**? Or should I make **b** the first argument of **f**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) states, the signature of the function should be `fun(x, *args)` where `x` is the parameter that is minimized for. So you can just use a small wrapper around your original function:

```
res = minimize(lambda b, a, c: f(a, b, c), x0=1, args=(a, c))
```